# run multi command in the same jupyter cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to display 2 output of 2 lines in the same time, I use Panda library and it seems like it display only the output of second line:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"state": ["Ohio", "Ohio", "Ohio", "Nevada", "Nevada"],
     "year": [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002],
     "pop": [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9]}

frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

this is My cell:

```
frame.state
frame.year
```

and this is the outputs:

[image]

Comment: If you want to print, use `print`.

Comment: Also you can use `display(...)`. Like that you can print more than one dataframe from one cell and they will look prettier than with `print`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run a cell with this at the beginning of the notebook:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

This will run all the expressions in each cell. If you want to return to the default behavior, you can write:

```
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "last_expr"
```

Comment: is InteractiveShell an environement variable, because a get the error: `name 'InteractiveShell' is not defined`

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I forgot to write down the import of `InteractiveShell`. It should work now.

Comment: it works fine, I would rather this way than the Print

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide two outputs at the same time you can try doing it this way. 
type this on your jupyter notebook cell,

frame.state , frame.year

Just insert a comma in between it will print Output for both the statements.