# google colab: running lines in one cell raises an error, but separating those lines into two cells does not

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, google-colaboratory

Running the following lines on google colab raises an `SystemError`:

```
voc_tok = df_asdf.VOC.apply(kkma.morphs).apply(Counter)
voc_test2 = voc_tok.isin(voc_etc)
```

[image]

However if I separate them into two cells, there is no such error; it works fine!

[image]

Do you guys have any idea why this kind of weird thing is happening? I truly have no idea...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [run multi command in the same jupyter cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036695/run-multi-command-in-the-same-jupyter-cells)

Comment: @Tranbi this is not about printing or returning multiple rows. The first line is just simply defining voc_tok. It does not need to return anything, does it?

Comment: I was referring to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48036735/13525512). Have you tried setting `InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"`?

Comment: @Tranbi Yes, but that is not working =[ However!! I just found that the issue is due to asynchronous programming. Simply putting `time.sleep(1)` after the first line solved the issue. Prob there are other ways than `time.sleep` tho = ] Thank you!